# Converting base64 to video

Tags: javascript, python, django, base64, python-3.11

i posted file by api in js of type string as shown in picture
[image: BUG-PIC]

so i need to convert str base64 to video file
when converting in python the generated file as shown in screenshot its lieke text
the `lesson_vid = request.POST.get('lesson_video')  print(type(lesson_vid))`
output is : <class 'str'>
the question is how to save mp4 video from str base64

python :

```
lesson_title = request.POST.get('lesson_title')
            lesson_vid = request.POST.get('lesson_video')[15:]
            lesson_vid = lesson_vid.encode()

            #print(lesson_vid)
            #lesson_vid = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in lesson_vid)

            with open("data/video1.mp4", "wb") as fh:
                fh.write(base64.b64decode(lesson_vid))
                fh.close()
            # if len(lesson_title) > 3:
            #     pass
            # if lesson_vid != 'no-vid':
            #     pass
```

javaScript :

```
c = console.log
    const inputFile = document.querySelector('#file');
    var vid_name = document.getElementById('vid-name')
    var video_upload = 'no-vid'
    inputFile.addEventListener('click', function () {
        inputFile.click();
    })
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const video = this.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            c(video.name)
            vid_name.innerHTML = video.name
            video_upload = reader.result
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(video);
    })


    document.getElementById('lesson-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
        console.log(file)

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('lesson_video', btoa(video_upload))
        formData.append('lesson_title', 'title')
        formData.append('lesson', 'd1')
        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}')


        $.post('/edit_course/{{ uid }}/', {
            'lesson_video': video_upload,
            'lesson': 'd1',
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        }, function (data, status) {



        });


    })
```

Comment: 1) please add your code as code formatted text to your question, not as a screenshot. 2) What exactly is the problem? I see that you already decode the string to binary and write the binary data to a file.

Comment: And of course you have to pay attention to what you really have here and what you convert. `data:video/mp4;base64,AAA...` is not a base64 string, but a data URL that contains a base64 string. The base64 string starts after `base64,`.

Comment: so if it is data URL how to convert it to video @jps

Answer (score 0):

fixed by only slicing the first indexes

````
lesson_vid = request.POST.get('lesson_video')[22:]

with open("data/video1.mp4", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.b64decode(lesson_vid))
    fh.close()```
````